# React- How to prevent activating all icons on 1 click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

How to prevent activating all icons on 1 click?

```
import React, { useState} from 'react'
import { FaPlus, FaMinus} from 'react-icons/fa'

function App2() {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false)

    function handleClick() {
        setClick(!click)
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div onClick={ handleClick}>
                {click ? <FaPlus /> : <FaMinus />}
                {click ? <FaPlus /> : <FaMinus />}
                {click ? <FaPlus /> : <FaMinus />}
                { click ? <FaPlus/> : <FaMinus/>}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default App2
```

Comment: The problem is your `click` in your conditional statement

Comment: What is the problem? As without 'click' it won't activate

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your `click` in your conditional statements, ***you've only one `click` state`***, so naturally they all will toggle at the same time.

To resolve you should have unique state for all elements you want to toggle.

Example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaPlus, FaMinus } from "react-icons/fa";

function App2() {
  // Use an array to store each click boolean
  const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(new Array(4).fill(false));

  const handleClick = (index) => () => {
    // Map the previous array of booleans to a new array
    // Toggle the element at the specific index
    setClicks((click) => click.map((el, i) => (i === index ? !el : el)));
  };
  
  // Map the array of click booleans
  // Assing a div and onClick to each pair of "+"/"-" icons
  return clicks.map((click, i) => (
    <div onClick={handleClick(i)}>{click ? <FaPlus /> : <FaMinus />}</div>
  ));
}
```

[image: Edit react-how-to-prevent-activating-all-icons-on-1-click]